# How to plot a bar chart with column name aligning to center at x- axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have created a bar chart using matplotlib but not able to align the names on the x-axis to center. Below is the screenshot. Can anyone please help me on this?

[image: How to align the public and private to the center]

Comment: You need to post your code for us to be able to help.

Comment: Instead of writing your code with standard matplotlib, you can use plotting via pandas or seaborn to get this kind of plots in a much more intuitive way. It helps to organize your data as a dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @JohanC, you can use pandas to do it automatically:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "private": [1, 1, 3],
        "public": [8, 12, 5],
    }
)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df.T.plot(kind="bar", rot=0, ax=ax)

plt.show()
```

[image: bar plot]

Comment: Thank you @paime. This worked perfectly for my use case